# Unix Find Replace Special Characters in Multiple Files

Tags: unix, shell, replace, find

I've got a set of files in a web root that all contain special characters that I'd like to remove (Â,€,â,etc).

My command

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec grep -il "Â" {} \;
```

finds & lists out the files just fine, but my command

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec tr -d 'Â' '' \;
```

doesn't produce the results I'm looking for.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I should probably clarify. The results i'm looking for is to have the special characters deleted from all the files in which the special character currently resides.

Comment: That's what you said in your first sentence in the original question. My question was what does your `tr` command do that's different from what you expect?

Comment: Yeah, after I run the tr -d command and then re-run the first find command, it will still return the same results, when instead I want to delete every result.

Comment: Does your `sed` have the `-i` (in-place) option? If not, that may be the source of the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to replace all **non-ascii** characters in all files inside the current directory you could use:

```
find . -type f | xargs perl -pi.bak -e 's,[^[:ascii:]],,g'
```

afterwards you will have to find and remove all the '.bak' files:

```
find . -type f -a -name \*.bak | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking into [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed). It can be used to replace the contents of the file.

So you could use the command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sed -i "s/Â//" {} \;
```

I have tested this with a simple example and it seems to work. The `-exec` should handle files with whitespace in their name, but there may be other vulnerabilities I'm not aware of.

Comment: I was able to get this one to work with a few additional flags

find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sed -i "s/Â//gi" {} \;

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
tr -d 'Â'
```

What does the ' ' stands for? On my system using your command produces this error:

> tr: extra operand `'
>
> Only one string may be given when deleting without squeezing repeats.
>
> Try `tr --help' for more information.

Comment: The '' was just to throw the character into quotes, replacing it with nothing

Comment: tr -d 'Â' just deletes, I think it's fine with what you need, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ø//' file.txt
```

That should do the trick for replacing a special char with an empty string.

```
find . -name "*.*" -exec sed 's/ø//' {} \
```

Comment: useless use of cat -- sed 's/ø//' file.txt

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this.

```
for file in `find . -type f`
do
    # Search for char end remove it. Save file as file.new
    sed -e 's/[Â€â]//g' $file > $file.new
    # mv file.new to file DON'T RUN IF YOU WILL NOT OVERITE ORIGINAL FILE
    mv $file.new $file
done
```

The above script will fail as levislevis85 has mentioned it with spaces in filenames. This would not be the case if you use the following code.

```
find . -type f | while read file
do 
    # Search for char end remove it. Save file as file.new
    sed -e 's/[Â€â]//g' "$file" > "$file".new
    # mv file.new to file DON'T RUN IF YOU WILL NOT OVERITE ORIGINAL FILE
    mv "$file".new "$file"
done
```

Comment: Okay, did not think that someone uses spaces in filenames in a linux environment. But you right, it's a point. I will add a correction to my post.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what "doesn't produce the results I'm looking for" means. However, in your command `tr` is not provided with the filenames to process. You could change it to this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec tr -d 'Â' {} \;
```

Which is going to output everything to stdout. You probably want to modify the files instead. You can use **Grundlefleck**'s answer, but one of the issues alluded to in that answer is if there are large numbers of files. You can do this:

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sed -i "s/Â//" \{\}
```

which should handle files with spaces in their names as well as large numbers of files.

Comment: sorry, the results I'm looking for is to have the special character deleted.

Comment: With both Grundlefleck's & the solution above I get a 
sed: 1: "./index.html": invalid command code .
Checking to see if I have a sys/environment setting that needs to be changed - but I don't think that's it

Answer (score 0):

with bash shell

```
for file in *.*
do
  case "$file" in 
   *[^[:ascii:]]* )
         mv "$file" "${file//[^[:ascii:]]/}"
   ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: I would upvote for the nice "trick" (however it was not a question about moving files around).